# Use one md-switch to toggle a group of other md-switchs in HTML/JS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am wanting to be able to toggle and untoggle entire group sections.  When the group section is toggled off, I want the sections in the group to toggle off as well or be disabled.  If the group section is toggled on, I want the sections toggled on as well or enabled.  I added `ng-change` to the group toggle with the function `toggleLayerGroup`.  I also have a `forEach` inside the function that goes through the feeds in the group.  I am just not sure what to add to turn off or on the feeds in the group.

Controller

This is where the feeds are loaded up.

```
// -- load feeds
  if (Service.currentUser.feeds) {
    var feeds = Service.currentUserOrg.feeds;
    angular.forEach(feeds, function(feed, index) {
      var lg = $scope.layerGroups[feed.category];
      if(lg) {
        lg.feeds[feed.id] = feed;
        lg.feeds[feed.id].layerState = Service.currentUser.mapState.visibleLayers.indexOf(feed.id) >= 0;
        if (lg.feeds[feed.id].layerState) {
          lg.state = true;
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

This is where the switches are hit.

```
$scope.layerState = false;
$scope.layerGroup = false;

$scope.toggleLayer = function (layerState, feed) {
  if (layerState) {
    subscribeFeed(feed);

    if (Service.currentUser.mapState.visibleLayers.indexOf(feed.id) < 0) {
      Service.currentUser.mapState.visibleLayers.push(feed.id);
      $scope.saveState();
    }
  }
  else {
    unsubscribeFeed(feed);

    var index = Service.currentUser.mapState.visibleLayers.indexOf(feed.id);
    if (index >= 0) {
      Service.currentUser.mapState.visibleLayers.splice(index, 1);
      $scope.saveState();
    }
  }
};

$scope.toggleLayerGroup = function (layerGroupState, layerGroup) {
  if (!layerGroupState) {
    angular.forEach(layerGroup.feeds, function (feed, index) {
      subscribeFeed(feed);
      $scope.saveState();
    });
  }
  else {
    angular.forEach(layerGroup.feeds, function (feed, index) {
      unsubscribeFeed(feed);
      $scope.saveState();
    });
  }
};

function subscribeFeed(feed) {
  switch (feed.category) {
    case 'people':
    case 'assets':
      feed._markerColl = {};
      feed.processEntity = processEntity;
      feed.clearFeed = clearFeed;
      break;
    case 'places':
      feed._placeColl = {};
      feed.processEntity = processEntity;
      feed.clearFeed = clearFeed;
      break;
  }
  feed.icons = Service.currentUser.feedIcons;
  feed.off = NextService.on(feed.id, function (data) {
    feed.processEntity(data);
  });

function unsubscribeFeed(feed) {
  feed.off();
  delete feed.off;
  NextService.emit('unsubscribe', {id: feed.id});
  feed.clearFeed();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got this to work properly.  These are the changes I made.

HTML

```
<!--LAYER TOGGLE SWITCH-->
        <md-switch class="md-primary" ng-model="layerGroup.state" ng-change="toggleLayerGroup(layerGroup)" aria-label="{{layerGroup.displayName}} Toggle Switch"></md-switch>

<!--LAYER FEEDS-->
      <div  ng-repeat="feed in layerGroup.feeds" layout="row" layout-align="start center" style="padding: 0 16px;">
        <!--FEED NAME-->
        <p flex class="m2" style="color: #FFFFFF;" ng-style="{ 'opacity' : layerGroup.state ? '1' : '.3' }">{{feed.name}}</p>
        <!--FEED SWITCH-->
        <md-switch class="md-primary" ng-model="feed.layerState" ng-disabled="!layerGroup.state" ng-change="toggleLayer(feed)" aria-label="{{feed.name}} Toggle Switch"></md-switch>
      </div>
```

I added `ng-style` to show when the feeds are disabled.  And `ng-disabled` to disable the switch when the `layerGroupState` is false.

Controller

```
// -- load feeds
  if (EcosystemService.currentUserOrg.feeds) {
    var feeds = EcosystemService.currentUserOrg.feeds;
    angular.forEach(feeds, function(feed, index) {
      var lg = $scope.layerGroups[feed.category];
      if(lg) {
        lg.feeds[feed.id] = feed;
        lg.feeds[feed.id].layerState = EcosystemService.currentUser.mapState.visibleLayers.indexOf(feed.id) >= 0;
        if (lg.feeds[feed.id].layerState) {
          lg.state = true;
        }
      }
    });
  }

$scope.toggleLayerGroup = function (layerGroup) {
  if (layerGroup.state) {
    angular.forEach(layerGroup.feeds, function (feed) {
      subscribeFeed(feed);

      if (EcosystemService.currentUser.mapState.visibleLayers.indexOf(feed.id) < 0) {
        EcosystemService.currentUser.mapState.visibleLayers.push(feed.id);
        $scope.saveState();
      }
      feed.layerState = true;
    });
  }
  else {
    angular.forEach(layerGroup.feeds, function (feed) {
      unsubscribeFeed(feed);

      var ndex = EcosystemService.currentUser.mapState.visibleLayers.indexOf(feed.id);
      if (ndex >= 0) {
        EcosystemService.currentUser.mapState.visibleLayers.splice(ndex, 1);
        $scope.saveState();
      }
      feed.layerState = false;
    });
  }
};
```

I added code to the place where the feeds are loaded and added code in `toggleLayerGroup` that will change the layerState dependending on the value of the layerGroup.

Answer (score 0):

Your `toggleLayerGroup` function should run a loop over `layerGroup.feeds` which will have the toggle's state info in them. For each value of `layerGroup.feed` it should pass it to `toggleLayer` function which will manage the subscription and view states.

While you are doing this, just find the state of `toggleLayerGroup` and pass it to each feed value for a group controlled view behavior.